# Using Partial_fit() method in RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, training-data

Is there any way I can take advantage of the partial_fit() method applied to RandomForestRegressor. Intention is to reuse the trained model incrementally with new .I do not want to use regular SGD.A
sample code would be of great help.

Comment: Try reading this answer. There is no partial_fit() method for scikitlearn's RandomForest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489667/combining-random-forest-models-in-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

Random Forest isn't an incremental learning algorithm (is what you are searching for). If you want to use an incremental learning algorithm in sklearn, [here you have a list of all the available algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning), which have implemented the partial_fit() method.

Comment: the link is broken, I could not edit it at the moment, here is an updated link: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning